# Systemd unit file works manually but not on boot

Tags: systemd

I made a simple systemd service file to run a command at boot:

```
[Unit]
Description=Executable Service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/path/to/command
```

It only needs to run once at boot.  I then enabled it:

```
systemctl enable executable.service

systemctl is-enabled executable.service
enabled
```

Then I reboot the server (it's running CentOS 7.3) and it doesn't run, I just get:

```
systemctl status executable.service
● executable.service - Executable Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/executable.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Once I start the service manually:

```
systemctl start executable.service
```

It works without issue like i would expect.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to *Install* it to an target. I.e. add the following secton:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```